# Is clientid of durable subsucription unique between brokers which are connected by network connector?

Tags: activemq-classic

- BrokerA and BrokerB are connected by network connector
- BrokerA and BrokerB have Topic "testTopic" as same name
- DurableSubscriber1 connects to testTopic of Broker**A**
- DurableSubscriber2 connects to testTopic of Broker**A** too
- DurableSubscriber3 connects to testTopic of Broker**B**
- ClientID of 3 DurableSubscribers is same ID "testID"

First, I create DurableSubscriber1. Next, I create DurableSubscriber**2**. But I can't create DurableSubscriber2. I think because DurableSubscriber can't be created as same ClientID.

However, after I create DurableSubscriber1, I can create DurableSubscriber**3**.

Are DurableSubsucriptions that is same clientid and connect to same Topic of different brokers different DurableSubsucriptions for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The durable subscriptions are distinct among ActiveMQ brokers so a client connected to broker A can create a durable subscription that has different messages stored than another client on broker B with the same client ID.  This is one reason that durable subscriptions are not always a good choice for networks of brokers, as message can become stranded if a subscriber is diconnected and then reconnected to another broker as it will result in the messages from its older subscription becoming stranded until it returns to the broker.